# awk field separator distinguish between -1, 10, and 1

Tags: awk, match

Let's say I have a text file:

```
>>cat tmp.txt
1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 10 10 10 10 10
```

I want to find the number of unique occurrences of the number 1, -1, and 10. The following is what I have thus far:

```
awk -F '-1' '{print NF-1,NR}' tmp.txt | awk '{print $1}'
awk -F '10' '{print NF-1,NR}' tmp.txt | awk '{print $1}'
awk -F '1' '{print NF-1,NR}' tmp.txt | awk '{print $1}'
```

Where the output is 5, 5, and 15 instead of 5, 5, and 5. It appears the awk command is finding *every* instance of 1 for the final command. How can this be handled properly?

Comment: `1` is a substring of `-1` and `10`.

Comment: `awk '{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i=="1") {a++} };print a}' tmp.txt`, see https://ideone.com/hzHpM3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `1` field separator matches `1` anywhere in the string, regardless of the context.

A valid awk approach here is to use the default whitespace field separator and count the value of those fields that are equal to `1`.

I suggest using

```
awk '{a=0;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if($i=="1") {a++} };print a}' tmp.txt
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/hzHpM3).

This awk command assigns a `0` to the `a` variable, then iterates over all the fields (with `for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {...}`) and increments `a` upon finding a field with the `1` value (see `if($i=="1") {a++} }`), then prints the `a` value.

Answer (score 1):

Use the default separator:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)cnt[$i]++};END{for(i in cnt)print i,cnt[i]}'
```